# no ioctl command

Tags: linux-kernel, ioctl

While running the function in kernel space

```
kernel_sock_ioctl(socket, FIONBIO, &on)
```

it returns error ENOIOCTLCMD 515 /* No ioctl command */

But when executing the same function in userspace

```
ioctl(s, FIONBIO, &on)
```

it succeeds

Why is ioctl missed for the same function in kernel space and how to handle it?

How to apply FIONBIO ioctl in kernel space?

Comment: Some ideas that come to mind when reading your question : How is `socket` created ? I assume `s` is a file descriptor returned after having created a socket. On the other hand, are the headers included in your source files having the same definition of `FIONBIO` ?

Comment: socket is created successfully in both cases. There are no warnings, recv and send succeed. Header asm-generic/ioctls.h, where FIONBIO is defined, is included to the source file.

Comment: And what does your kernel tell you ? You might have some dmesg lines that can help ?

Comment: dmesg message after socket created [ 2360.847927] DEV  eth0 -> 00:1a:92:9c:99:8a: ioctl set non-blocking i/o failed: error -515
[ 2360.847930] DEV  eth0 -> 00:1a:92:9c:99:8a: close receive socket